# paste() within another function

Tags: r, data.table, paste

The first function works and the second one does not, and I am not sure why. I am solely interested in what is happening with the paste() function in this example, as all of the other code works properly. In addition to what is shown below, I have also tried the second function with a comma separator between each value.

Ideally, the list would be as follows, within my function but with the paste() function instead of my listing these values.

X41262.0.0 = i.X41262.0.0, X41262.0.1 = i.X41262.0.1, etc.

```
fread("ukb33822.csv", select= c("eid", "X2784.0.0", "X2794.0.0", 
                                        "X2804.0.0", "X2814.0.0", "X2834.0.0", 
                                        "X3536.0.0", "X3546.0.0", paste("X41262.0.", 0:65, sep = ""), 
                                        "X3581.0.0"))



biobank[biobank2, on = .(eid), `:=` (X2784.0.0 = i.X2784.0.0, X2794.0.0 = i.X2794.0.0, 
                                 X2804.0.0 = i.X2804.0.0, X2814.0.0 = i.X2814.0.0, 
                                 X2834.0.0 = i.X2834.0.0, X3536.0.0 = i.X3536.0.0, 
                                 X3546.0.0 = i.X3546.0.0, paste("X41262.0.", 0:65, " = ", "i.X41262.0.", 0:65, sep = ""),
                                 X3581.0.0 = i.X3581.0.0)]

Error in 
`[.data.table`(biobank, biobank2, on = .(eid), `:=`(X2784.0.0 = i.X2784.0.0,  : 
  In `:=`(col1=val1, col2=val2, ...) form, all arguments must be named.
```

Comment: R is not a macro language.  When you put `paste("X41262.0.", 0:65, " = ", "i.X41262.0.", 0:65, sep = "")` in as an argument to a function, the function receives the character vector resulting from that call, it doesn't interpret that character vector as a collection of arguments.

Comment: Would I use something like lapply here then? What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Looks like @r2evans has really good suggestions in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having your data, it's a little contrived, but this might be enough to show you one option:

```r
DT <- data.table(x=1:3)
DT[, c("a", "b", letters[3:5]) := c(list(1, 2), 3:5) ]
DT
#    x a b c d e
# 1: 1 1 2 3 4 5
# 2: 2 1 2 3 4 5
# 3: 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

In this example:

- `"a"` and `"b"` are your already-known *names*, e.g., `"X2784.0.0"`, `"X2794.0.0"`, etc
- `letters[3:5]` are *names* you need to create programmatically, e.g., `paste0("X41262.0.", 0:65)`
- `1` and `2` are your already-known *values*, e.g., `i.X2784.0.0`, `i.X2794.0.0`, etc
- `3:5` are *values* you determine programmatically

It is not clear to me where your other values are found ...

If they are in the enclosing environment (and not within the actual table), then perhaps:

```r
x1 <- 3:5
x2 <- 13:15
x3 <- 33:35
e <- environment()
DT[, c("a", "b", paste0("x", 1:3)) := c(list(1, 2), mget(paste0("x", 1:3), envir=e))]
#    x a b x1 x2 x3
# 1: 1 1 2  3 13 33
# 2: 2 1 2  4 14 34
# 3: 3 1 2  5 15 35
```

where `paste0("x", 1:3)` is forming the variable names, and `mget(...)` actually retrieves them. You might need to define `e` as I have here, if they are not visible from `data.table`'s search path.

If they are already in the `data.table`, then you might be able to do something with this:

```r
DT <- data.table(x1=1:3, x2=11:13, x3=21:23)
DT[, c("a", "b", paste0("y", 1:3)) := c(list(1, 2), DT[, paste0("x", 1:3), with=FALSE]) ]
#    x1 x2 x3 a b y1 y2 y3
# 1:  1 11 21 1 2  1 11 21
# 2:  2 12 22 1 2  2 12 22
# 3:  3 13 23 1 2  3 13 23
```

where `paste0("y", 1:3)` forms the names you want them to be, and `paste0("x", 1:3)` forms the other columns' names as they exist before this call.

Comment: If I want to use my existing code, is this not possible? I just want to select existing columns and add them to a different existing data.table. Is there no way to add in X41262.0.0 = i.X41262.0.0, X41262.0.1 = i.X41262.0.1, X41262.0.2 = i.X41262.0.2, X41262.0.3 = i.X41262.0.3, etc. to my code without aborting my existing code entirely? I can write them in individually, as well. I just thought there would be an easier way to add these terms to my existing code without having to manually add them all individually or change my code entirely.

Comment: As user2554330 said before, you can't do it quite that way. You cannot use your existing code as-is, R does not make that easy. I thought this was what you needed, though: if you can programmatically define the variable names (source and destination), then what about this answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for the help.